# Add OnPressed action to a widget flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to do a submit button for register but i got error each time i add onPressed, this is the code:

```dart
Widget _submitButton() {
  return Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade200,
              offset: Offset(2, 4),
              blurRadius: 5,
              spreadRadius: 2)
        ],
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [Color(0xff03a9f4), Color(0xff81d4fa)])),
    child: Text(
      'Register Now',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  );
}
```

What i should change to make the code work ? I want to connect with this button to firebase

Comment: Could you share onPressed() code

Comment: onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        registerToFb();
    }
    },

Comment: How and where did you add the onPressed?

Comment: after style ),)

Comment: check my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your widget in an `InkWell` and use the `onTap` property

```dart
Widget _submitButton() {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        registerToFb();
      }
    },  // use this
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                offset: Offset(2, 4),
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 2)
          ],
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Color(0xff03a9f4), Color(0xff81d4fa)])),
      child: Text(
        'Register Now',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

or you can use a `GestureDetector`

```dart
Widget _submitButton() {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
        registerToFb();
      }
    },  // use this
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                offset: Offset(2, 4),
                blurRadius: 5,
                spreadRadius: 2)
          ],
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Color(0xff03a9f4), Color(0xff81d4fa)])),
      child: Text(
        'Register Now',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the parent container with GestureDetector.

```
return GestureDetector(
     onTap: (){  doSomething();  }
     child: Container(
           .........
```